# Docusign remote email button border

Tags: html, css, view, docusignapi

While signing the documents using remote option in docusign we get the email with a button "**VIEW DOCUMENTS**" and when both the party signed the document we get an email with the button "**REVIEW DOCUMENT**".

All I want is a orange color border in both the buttons I already downloaded the email resource file and apply some styles but nothing seems working.

Please help

Comment: Please add code you tried.

Comment: There is no code  CodeRomeos its just the branding and Uploading a resource file which is an xml file containing all the styles.

Comment: One step I would use to troubleshoot is take a look at the raw contents of a sample email to see if your custom html is being honored or clobbered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change many visual aspects of the DocuSign UX by changing the *branding*. Please see the [Customer Support page about branding.](https://support.docusign.com/guides/cdse-admin-guide-branding)

Pro tip: keep a copy of your original branding file! Be careful as you make changes and test every change that you make.